# SqlAlchemy: Index postgresql_ops ignored when func.lower(column)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Index, String, MetaData, func, create_engine

md = MetaData()
tbl = Table('t1', md, Column('col1', String()))
idx = Index(
    'idx1',
    func.lower(tbl.c.col1),
    postgresql_ops={'col1': 'text_pattern_ops'},
)

e = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/test", echo=True)
with e.connect() as c:
    md.create_all(c)
```

Outputs

```
 Column |       Type        | Modifiers 
--------+-------------------+-----------
 col1   | character varying | 

Indexes:
    "idx1" btree (lower(col1::text))  # NO text_pattern_ops!!!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#operator-classes), you need to put a label on the expression:

```
idx = Index(
    'idx1',
    func.lower(tbl.c.col1).label('lower_col1'),
    postgresql_ops={'lower_col1': 'text_pattern_ops'},
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but yesterday this wasn't in the docs :)
@univerio

Comment: @VitaliPonomar Hah, saw the issue. :) For reference, there's a [separate issue](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3432/cant-use-postgresql_ops-for-expressions) where this was actually fixed, although it's not immediately clear from that issue that `.label` is what you need to do.